# Using WPF controls in a background or ASP.Net environment

Tags: asp.net, wpf

I have noticed that some WPF controls have some decent effects available to them (drop shadow, reflection etc), and was wondering if it was possible to use these WPF controls solely for their available effects?

For example, I have an image manipulation library that resizes and letterboxes disparate sized images but I would like to add drop shadow effects to the resulting images.  The WPF image control has this effect available, but how easy is it to use in an environment where there will never be a GUI (console app or ASP.Net library/handler for example).

Thoughts?

Cheers

Moo

Comment: I've recently written a post on a similar argument, [here](http://blog.letmecode.net/?p=19) .

Comment: Only if you fix the link.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23708905)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use them, yes.  The only problem is that you have to use them within STA threads, which you probably can't count on happening automagically (e.g., response threads in ASP.NET are MTA).

I'm using WPF controls in a windows service app.  I just have to transition to an STA thread before I do my rendering.

Comment: It would be rather difficult to get things right. I think a more realistic suggestion should be moving to Windows Image Components, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-most-common-technologies-not-supported-by-microsoft-8675c409bde2

Comment: @LexLi No, it's got nothing to do with the question asked seven years ago, and neither does your link have anything to do with WIC. Nice try, though.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at RenderTargetBitmap. You could do whatever with your WPF component, then render it as a bitmap, and then use that bitmap on your ASP page.

I'm not sure that is the best way of doing it though. Is Silverlight out of question for you?

Comment: Yes, I don't want a reliance on silverlight at all if possible, as I'm developing a library for handling the image manipulation rather than a front end tool.